# Keyboard shortcut in excel for expanding the pivot table row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, pivot-table

I'm able to expand/collapse the row in the pivot table with mouse by:

- right clicking on cell in the first column of the row + selecting "Expand/Collapse"/"Expand" from context menu.
- or double clicking on the cell in the first column of the row

Is there a keybord shortcut for same action? I'm interested in Excel 2007 and 2010 shortcuts.

EDIT: updated excel versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually access the context menu through the right mouse button or by pressing the menu/application key. The menu key is between between the right Control and Windows keys. In Excel 2010 you should be able to:

- Expand by selecting the cell, then pressing Menu, E, X
- Collapse by selecting the cell, then pressing Menu, E, O

Edit: In case you don't have a menu/application key, you may be able to access the context menu by pressing Shift+F10

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Menu Key</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> - expands all

<kbd>Menu Key</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> - collapses all

Answer (score -1):

Once you click on the item that has lower level items available your right arrow expands the lower level items and your left arrow collapses the lower level items

Comment: Not sure what version you are using but right and left arrows simply do not expand or collapse PivotTable fields in any version I have (so that's 2000, 2003, 2007, 2010 Beta), they just move one cell in that direction.

Comment: I had pulled it from a list of keyboard shortcuts in the Excel help files, but when I tried it after reading your comment you appear to be correct. Here is the quote from the Pivot Tables section of keyboard shortcuts. Maybe I misunderstood what they meant.

To do this Press 
 
For an item that has lower-level items available, displays the lower-level items.
 RIGHT ARROW
 
For an item that has lower-level items displayed, hides the lower-level items.
 LEFT ARROW

Answer (score -1):

For Excel 2007 you can try with:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>JT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to expand the field
<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>JT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to collapse the field

Answer (score -1):

Simply:

<kbd>Menu</kbd> - <kbd>E</kbd>

Hit the menu button on your keyboard followed by "e" on your keyboard.

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as the answer that has already been accepted. Can you clarify how your answer adds to the conversation or provides information not already here?